# How do applications like AppZapper on OSX locate files used by an application?

Tags: macos, uninstall

[AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com/) is an application used on osx to find and remove all files related to an application like cache and preferences.

Does anybody know how to do the same from the terminal in a guaranteed manner or does AppZapper use heuristic to determine application related files.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably by using a mix of:

- the BOM files previously in Library/Receipts now in /private/var/db/receipts (since Snow Leopard I believe).
- automated removed of preferences files associated to the application (as an option at least).
- and some pre-programmed knowledge of specific applications.

Try to use the command line utility `lsbom` on any of the .bom file in the receipts directory and you should get the list of the files deployed by a specific installer.

Comment: `plutil` is a friendlier interface to the package system.